# In MongoDB, how do I combine objects from the same collection or pipeline into a array based on same key?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following output an aggregation pipeline, or data stored in a collection:

```
{
  {
    "name":"sam",
    "data": {
              "category":"pen",
              "count":"2"
            } 
  },

  {
    "name":"sam",
    "data": {
              "category":"pencil",
              "count":"5"
            } 
  },

  {
    "name":"steve",
    "data": {
              "category":"pencil",
              "count":"1"
            } 
  }
}
```

How can I get a output such as:

```
{
  {
    "name":"sam",
    "data" : [{
               "category":"pen",
               "count":"2"
              },
              {
               "category":"pencil",
               "count":"5"
             }]
  },

  {
    "name":"steve",
    "data": [{
               "category":"pencil",
               "count":"1"
            }]
  }
}
```

Or even better, though I'm not sure this is possible

```
{
  {
    "name":"sam",
    "data": {
              "pen":"2",
              "pencil":"5"
            }
  },

  {
    "name":"steve",
    "data": {
              "pencil":"1",
            }
  }
}
```

Apologies if the title is bad, I searched profusely and I am at a loss as to how to phrase this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the Aggregation stage [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with the Aggregation Operator `$push` to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$data.category",
          v: "$data.count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AwCYbUwm6qf) | [Alternative `Category` repeats](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kpc1rOGu3zb)